# JApplet: How to use browser's ssl-session for clienthauth from within a Java applet

Tags: java, browser, ssl, applet, client-side

Is it possible for a Java Applet to use the SSL Session of the browser?

I have a webpage with a `JApplet` on it. This webpage is protected by SSL client-authentication. From within the `JApplet` I need to request a second script(`php`, `jsp` - whatever) on the client-auth protected server. But I need to do it without authenticating again. So is it possible to make the applet use the already authenticated ssl-context of the browser?

thanks in advance...
daniel

Comment: Hi Daniel, Did you have any success with this?